# How many to rearrange the letters of the word “MAMMAL”. What if all M’s must be together?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am trying to get my head around an idea but I can't seem to get it to work.

Imagine you have the word "MAMMAL"

Lets see I wanted to figure out how many ways I could rearrange the letters. Well that is easy. It is simply

6!/3!2! = 60 possibilities

But what if I added a restriction to it such that all M's must be together.

Then I could consider all M's as one letter and it would be 4!/2! = 12 possibilities.

Again I understand that. But what if the restriction was there needs to be a minimum of 2 M's together at all times.

If I were to do the same process as the previous example, I would combine 2 M's into one. Which then would become 5!/2! = 60.

This seems to be a wrong answer because it is the same as my first calculation of finding all possibilities without any restrictions. Can anyone please explain to me as to how I need to approach the last problem of finding number of combinations where at least 2 M's are always together? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your answer is incorrect is the following: When you consider **MM** one letter, then you need to remember there is another M around too. So for example, you counted M**MM**AAL and **MM**MAAL separately which is why you got $60$, more than what you should've gotten.

In order to rectify that, just begin with $5!/2!$ and then *subtract* the doubly counted ones. Notice that for all the cases where there are three M's together, you get this double counting situation. There are 12 cases where the three M's are together so you counted 12 of them *twice* therefore you subtract 12 to get $60 - 12 =48$ as your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

If you don't mind me asking. Would the same process work if for example I added an additional M to the word (ex. MMMMAAL). Would I do the same process? Combine two of the M's but subtract that by the combinations of 3 m's together and 4 m's together. I tried that but I didn't seem to work out. I know that answer is 3 but I don't get anywhere close to that

Comment: That would be a good deal tougher. Notice that in that case when four M's are together, you have **MM** MMAAL, M **MM** MAAL, MM **MM** AAL which are all the same. In other words, you'll need to subtract the combinations of 4 M's together *twice* instead of once. But the answer cannot be three. If I didn't make a mistake, I believe it is 102. By the way, for this problem, I strongly suggest using the method used by the other person who answered this question, it will be much easier. But you could, for the sake of better understanding, try to solve it using this method, but be careful!

Comment: Got it thanks! I will try both ways and see what happens. Yes I made a mistake when I said 3. There are 3 combinations if you don't want 2 MM's to be together. The total number of combinations without restrictions is 105 so yes the answer is 102. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Consider the complimentary event, which is no Ms are together, i.e. all Ms are separate.

3 Ms need to be put in 6 places. There are only 4 choices, M _ M _ M _,  _ M _ M _M, M _ M _ _ M and M _ _ M _ M.

In remaining 3 places, you need to put 3 letters, out of which 2 are different. Therefore, there are $4\times\dfrac{3!}{2!} = 12$ such words ($4$ for $4$ different arrangements described above).

Subtract this from total words $60$, and you'll get your answer as $48$.

Comment: This is incorrect, what about the case M_M_ _ M and so on?

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi Fixed. Have I missed any case?

Comment: Nope, now it is correct. Easy to overlook cases in such problems.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi Thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!